# A system of linear equations with a parameter

Tags: matrices

I am new to matrices, but I am trying to solve the following system of linear equations with a parameter:

$$\begin{cases}\lambda x_1+3x_2+x_3=0\\(\lambda+1)x_1+0x_2-x_3=0\\(2\lambda-1)x_1+2x_2+4x_3=0\end{cases}$$
We have:

$$ \begin{pmatrix}
        \lambda & 3 & 1 &0 \\
        \lambda+1 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
        2\lambda-1 & 2 & 4 & 0 \\ 
      \end{pmatrix}$$

I was able to write it as $$ \begin{pmatrix}
        1-2\lambda & -15 & -4 &0 \\
        1 & -3 & -2 & 0 \\
        2\lambda-1 & 2 & 4 & 0 \\ 
      \end{pmatrix}$$

I really don't see how I am supposed to write it in a triangular Matrix form.

Thank you advance!

Comment: Remember that you can multiply any row by a constant and add it to another row. If we assume $\lambda\neq 0$, we can multiply the first row by $-(\lambda+1)/\lambda$ and add it to the second row. The first element of the second row becomes zero. Do the same to the third row. Then, you can use the second row to eliminate the second entry in the third row. By this time, you have a triangular matrix.

Comment: When you get time , you should verify whether my Answer works out , Do let me know whether there is something missing.

Answer (score 1):

We can "Add" Eq2 & Eq3 to get :
$ 3 \lambda x_1 + 2 x_2 + 3 x_3 = 0 $

We can then "Subtract" 3 times Eq1 to get :
$ [3 \lambda - 3 \lambda] x_1 + [2-9] x_2 + [3 - 3] x_3 = 0 $

That will give $ -7 x_2 = 0 $ & hence $ x_2 = 0 $ always.

We can then leave out $ x_2 $ to make Eq1 & Eq2 like this :
$ [\lambda ] x_1 + x_3 = 0 $
$ [\lambda + 1] x_1 - x_3 = 0 $

We then "Add" these to get :
$ [ 2 \lambda + 1 ] x_1 = 0 $

This gives either $ x_1 = 0 $ ( which will also make $ x_3 = 0 $ ) or $ [ 2 \lambda + 1 ] = 0 $ ( which makes $\lambda = -1/2$ )

Hence the Solutions will be :
$ (x_1,x_2,x_3) = (2z,0,z) $ ( where $z$ is Some Arbitrary Constant ) when $\lambda$ is $-1/2$
$(x_1,x_2,x_3) = (0,0,0)$ when $\lambda$ has other values

That is the Complete Solution Set.

ADDENDUM :

[[ 1 ]] We can then see that :
When $ \lambda = -1/2 $ , we get Equations where $ (2,0,1) $ & $ (-6,0,-3) $ are Example Solutions.
When $ \lambda $ has other values , the Equations have Solution $(0,0,0)$ which always works.

[[ 2 ]] We can make it via "Triangular Matrix" by re-writing the Equations with Order $ (x_3,x_2,x_1) $
That will make it easier to "Multiply" & "Divide" the Equations by Constants not involving $ \lambda $ & hence easier to visualize.
Eventually , the Complete Solution Set will be Equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Let:
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
        \lambda & 3 & 1  \\
        \lambda+1 & 0 & -1  \\
        2\lambda-1 & 2 & 4  \\ 
      \end{pmatrix}$$
therfore:
$$A.\begin{pmatrix}
        x_1\\
        x_2\\
        x_3  \\ 
      \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
        0\\
        0\\
        0\\ 
      \end{pmatrix} $$

using Methode [Crammer's Rule](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%27s_rule)

we have : $$det(A_i)=\begin{vmatrix}
        0 & 3 & 1  \\
        0 & 0 & -1  \\
        0 & 2 & 4  \\ 
      \end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix}
        \lambda & 0 & 1  \\
        \lambda+1 & 0 & -1  \\
        2\lambda-1 & 0 & 4  \\ 
      \end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix}
        \lambda & 3 & 0  \\
        \lambda+1 & 0 & 0  \\
        2\lambda-1 & 2 & 0  \\ 
      \end{vmatrix}=0$$
and we have : $$x_i=\frac{det(A_i)}{det(A)}=\frac{0}{det(A)}=0$$
finnaly:$$x_1=x_2=x_3=0$$

Answer (score 0):

Because it is a homogeneous equation (equals zero) it only has a solution when the ${\rm det}(A)=0$

$$ \left| \begin{bmatrix}
        \lambda & 3 & 1 &0 \\
        \lambda+1 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
        2\lambda-1 & 2 & 4 & 0 \\ 
      \end{bmatrix} \right| = 0 $$

has a solution when $\lambda = -\tfrac{4}{11}$

So now you have

$$ \begin{bmatrix}
  -\tfrac{4}{11} & 3 & 1 \\
  \tfrac{7}{11} & 0 & -1 \\
  -\tfrac{19}{11} & 2 & 4 \end{bmatrix} \pmatrix{x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 } = \pmatrix{0 \\ 0 \\ 0} $$

Multiply each row of $A$ on order to make the leading coefficient equal to $1$

$$ \begin{bmatrix} 1 & -\tfrac{33}{4} & - \tfrac{11}{4} \\ 1 & 0 & -\tfrac{11}{7} \\ 1 & -\tfrac{22}{19} & -\tfrac{33}{19} \end{bmatrix} \pmatrix{x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 } = \pmatrix{0 \\ 0 \\ 0}$$

and subtract the first row from the 2nd and 3rd rows

$$ \begin{bmatrix} 1 & -\tfrac{33}{4} & - \tfrac{11}{4} \\ 0 & \tfrac{33}{4} & \tfrac{33}{28} \\ 0 & \tfrac{539}{76} & \tfrac{77}{76} \end{bmatrix} \pmatrix{x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 } = \pmatrix{0 \\ 0 \\ 0}$$

and again make the leading coefficients equal to $1$

$$ \begin{bmatrix} 1 & -\tfrac{33}{4} & - \tfrac{11}{4} \\ 0 & 1 & \tfrac{1}{7} \\ 0 & 1 & \tfrac{1}{7} \end{bmatrix} \pmatrix{x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 } = \pmatrix{0 \\ 0 \\ 0}$$

and as you can see when subtracting the 2nd row from the 3rd row the final row is zero which means that one of $x_1$,$x_2$ or $x_3$ is arbitrary, and the others depend on it

$$ \begin{bmatrix} 1 & -\tfrac{33}{4} & - \tfrac{11}{4} \\ 0 & 1 & \tfrac{1}{7} \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \pmatrix{x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 } = \pmatrix{0 \\ 0 \\ 0}$$

When you multiply out the equations you get

$$ \begin{cases} x_1 - \tfrac{33}{4} x_2 - \tfrac{11}{4} x_3 & = 0 \\ x_2 + \tfrac{1}{7} x_3 & = 0
\end{cases} $$

that has the solution

$$ \begin{cases}
   x_1 &= \tfrac{11}{7} x_3 \\ 
   x_2 &= -\tfrac{1}{7} x_3 \\
   x_3 &= \text{(arbitrary)}
\end{cases}$$